# Javascript ¿Cómo puedo comprobar que dos objetos JSON sean iguales?

Tags: javascript

Suponiendo que tengo dos copias del mismo objeto exactamente iguales y una con alguna diferencia:

```
let uno  = {"nombre": "Daniela", "edad": 24};
let dos  = {"nombre": "Daniela", "edad": 24};
let tres = {"nombre": "Daniela", "edad": 25};
```

Si los comparo de la siguiente manera me dan todos false:

```
console.log(a == b); // False
console.log(a === b); // False
console.log(a == c); // False
console.log(a === c); // False
```

Pero quisiera saber como poder compararlos para que al comparar el objeto `a` con el objeto `b` me de un `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si el orden de las propiedades en tus objetos no va a cambiar, puedes usar `JSON.stringify` asi:

```js
let a  = {"nombre": "Daniela", "edad": 24};
let b  = {"nombre": "Daniela", "edad": 24};
let c = {"nombre": "Daniela", "edad": 25};

console.log(JSON.stringify(a) == JSON.stringify(b)); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b));
console.log(JSON.stringify(a) == JSON.stringify(c)); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(c));
```

Comment: esta manera creo que es sencilla y funcional, +1

Answer (score 1):

Una manera es buscar en todo el objeto **A** mediante su **key**, preguntando si el objeto **B** tambien tiene ese mismo **key** y luego ir preguntando si ese **key** esta anexado al mismo valor en los dos objetos, dejo mi codigo.

```js
let uno = {
  "nombre": "Daniela",
  "edad": 24
};
let dos = {
  "nombre": "Daniela",
  "edad": 24,
  "edad2": 24
};
let tres = {
  "nombre": "Daniela",
  "edad": 25
};
let cuatro = {
  "nombre": "Daniela",
  "edad": 24
};
console.log(equals(uno, dos));
console.log(equals(uno, tres));
console.log(equals(uno, cuatro));

function equals(a, b) {
  if (Object.keys(a).length === Object.keys(b).length) {
    for (let current of Object.keys(a)) {
      if (!tienePropiedad(b, current, a[current]))
        return false
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function tienePropiedad(a, property, ele) {
  if (a.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    let data = a[property];
    if (data === ele)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta no funciona si le agregas una tercera propiedad al segundo objeto.

Comment: @alanfcm edite mi respuesta, gracias por la observacion